# char[] vs LPCSTR strange behavior

Tags: c++, windows, arrays, char, lpcstr

Could you please explain why, in order to convert a char array like this:

```
char strarr[5] = {65,83,67,73,73}; //ASCII
```

Into `LPCSTR` to be accepted by `GetModuleHandleA()` and `GetProcAddress()`, I have to first append `0` to the end ?

i.e. I have:

```
char strarr[6] = {65,83,67,73,73,0};
```

And only then convert as `(LPCSTR)&strarr`.

For some reason I don't get the first one works only sometimes (i.e. if I do not add `0` at the end), while if I do add zero at the end - this work all the time. Why do I have to add zero?

Oh and a side question - why in C++ do I have to explicitly state the size of array in [], when I am initializing it with elements right away? (If I don't state the size, then it does not work)

Thanks.

Comment: I made your question a little bit more readable. Please, do it yourself next time to give your questions better chances of being answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those functions expect `NULL` terminated strings.

Since you only give them a pointer to a char array, they can't possibily know its size, hence the need for a particular value (the terminating `NULL` character) to indicate the end of the string.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for a quick answer. Do I also have to append 0 to char arrays when expected value is const char * and not LPCSTR?

Comment: Its ASCII `NUL` character, and not `NULL`.

Comment: @George Yes, almost all strings in C are null-terminated character arrays.

Comment: @George: `LPCSTR` is actually a `define` for `const char*` so yes :)